# How to create this style of article in LaTeX

Tags: templates

Does anyone know how to define the environment of [this kind of article](http://www.econ.yale.edu/~ka265/research/ACDR/ACDRdraft.pdf) in LaTeX?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! please develop, sorry but i didn't understand what do you mean you did reduce the search perimeter in a PDF document of 48 pages.

Comment: Hello there, welcome to the site! If it's practical to do so, it might be nice to include a screenshot demonstrating what you're looking for. In general one of the reasons for this is so that people don't have to follow unfamiliar links, although this one looks pretty safe to me! But another reason is what if that link goes dead? Your whole question will be useless to future visitors, so it's always *nice* if questions can be as self-contained as possible. Within reason of course, nothing wrong with a link, and proper attribution is essential, but including some of the meat of the link is a +

Comment: This looks pretty much like a regular `article` document apart from the margins (which you can set with the `geometry` package).  The author blocks can be done with a `tabular` environment. The font used is Palatino (with the `mathpazo` package.)

Comment: I've seen this style in several papers issued by MIT-based economists. You may want to write to Professor Arnaud Costinot and ask him if might point you to a website from which you might download a set of LaTeX templates.

Comment: Building on what @Mico said here is a [link](http://www.mit.edu/~westj/templates/JWest_article_template.tex) to the potential desired template (updated 2016-3-16).

Comment: @SAM You should make that an answer!

Answer (score 1):

Building on [@Mico's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318474/how-to-create-this-style-of-article-in-latex/318482#comment777846_318474), here is a [**link**](http://www.mit.edu/~westj/templates/JWest_article_template.tex) to the potential desired template, from the Dept. of Economics (MIT), written by Jeremy West (last update 2016-3-16).

Since the link to the file I posted doesn't contain a full template examples (like how to declare more than one author) you may want to contact the author of the template, or maybe some one from here will make some hacks if you precise what do you need exactly.

Comment: This is certainly not exactly the template that made the linked document. Link colours are different (blue, not dark red), Latin Modern instead of Palatino.  And frankly I would not recommend anyone to use this template document at all especially if you're not sure of what you are doing. To begin with it assumes `latin9` file encoding, whereas most of us use `utf8`. It also is designed for putting tables and figures at the end of the document (as is often required for journals.)  Better to learn the relevant packages you need for the tasks at hand than rely on someone's personal style.